# Time limit exceeded python

Tags: python-3.x

Im a newbie at python and i have a task. Given a number as input, i have to print the prime that belongs in the number/position on a list of primes starting from position 1 and not 0, until the input is 'END'. For example, if the input is 1, output should be the first prime which is 2, if the input is 5, output should be the 5th prime which is 11 and so. It works fine but after 3/4-digit numbers the output has a delay until i get the Error: Time limit exceeded. How can i make it run faster? Here's the code:

```
def primes_function(n):
    primes = []
    num = 2
    while len(primes) <= n:
        x = num // 2
        while x > 1:
            if num % x == 0:
                break
            x -= 1
        else:
            primes.append(num)
        num += 1

    return primes[n - 1]
#main
while True:
    n = input()

    if n == 'END':
        break

    elif n > '0':
        n = int(n)
        value = primes_function(n)
        print(value)
```

Sorry if i made any mistakes in the description
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB8K7.png)

Comment: One thing is that you could try and avoid building the `primes` list everythime your `prime_function` is called.  Try making `primes` global.

Comment: Where does that *»time limit exceeded«* even come from?

Comment: Try [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/158929).

Comment: Use Sieve of Eratosthenes to precalculate primes and store it in array. Use index to access the ith prime

Comment: @BrijRajKishore If you were tasked with finding the `n`th prime number, what list size would you choose for the Sieve of Eratosthenes?

Comment: Please paste the entire traceback here (Everything after "Traceback (most recent call last):"). That helps us to quickly understand exactly what happened.

Comment: Assuming the n <= to the max array size

Comment: @Socowi We have a forum that tests the code, i will post a picture right away.

Comment: @gripis Ah, I see. So your (robot) teacher runs your code and considers it to be too slow – that's not of interest here. You could just have said: *»I have this program and I want to make it faster«*. Anyways, check the answer linked by zipa.

Comment: Minor improvement: `num += 1` - make that `num += 2` to avoid testing even numbers. But also change to `primes = [2]; num = 3`. Or, just fill the list with the first 100 or so prime numbers from the internet. `primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19....]`.

Comment: I've tried the improvements of @zipa, it got a little better but still i get the same error at 4-digit numbers. Anyway, thank you all.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, please accept that answer to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

I combined [this answer **(1)**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/158929/185595) and [this answer **(2)**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/158928/185595) to speed up the function. The two key ideas are: When testing primality of a candidate ...

- ... do not divide by every number (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...) but only by the preceding prime numbers (2, 3, 5, ...). Every non-prime number > 2 is has to have some prime factor.
- ... divide only by numbers that are ≤ sqrt(candidate).

```
import math

def nth_prime(n):
        prime_list = [2]
        candidate = 3
        while len(prime_list) < n:
                max_factor = math.sqrt(candidate)
                is_prime = True
                for p in prime_list:
                        if p > max_factor:
                                break
                        elif candidate % p == 0:
                                is_prime = False
                                break
                if is_prime:
                        prime_list.append(candidate)
                candidate += 2
        return prime_list[-1]
```

## Benchmark of different solutions:

```
                       n=9000   n=15000   n=25000   n=75000
your solution       1m38.455s         -         -         -
linked answer (1)   0m 2.954s    8.291s   22.482s         -
linked answer (2)   0m 0.352s    0.776s    1.685s    9.567s
this answer         0m 0.120s    0.228s    0.410s    1.857s
Brij's answer       0m 0.315s    0.340s    0.317s    0.318s
```

For every `n` the programs where started from scratch.

As we can see, Brij's Sieve Of Eratosthenes takes a fairly low constant amount of time. If you want to find big prime numbers below a fixed limit then that's the best solution (here n < 78499, as the 78499-*th* prime number is 1 000 003 which is bigger than the sieve list).

If you also want to find a lot of smaller or medium sized prime numbers or cannot accept a fixed limit then go with this solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I should have known from mathematics that i only need to search till the sqrt of the given number. Really appreciate the help from everyone!

Answer (score 1):

```
def SieveOfEratosthenes(): 
    n = 1000000
    prime = [True for i in range(n+1)] 
    p = 2
    count = 0
    while (p * p <= n): 
        if (prime[p] == True): 
            count = count + 1
            for i in range(p * p, n+1, p): 
                prime[i] = False
        p += 1
    seive = []
    for p in range(2, n): 
        if prime[p]: 
            seive.append(p)

    return seive        

def primes_function(n , seive):
    return seive[n - 1]
#main
seive = SieveOfEratosthenes()
while True:
    n = input()
    if n == 'END':
        break
    elif n > '0':
        n = int(n)
        value = primes_function(n,seive)
        print(value)
```

Full working : https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/QTSGQfhFV3

I have precomputed the primes below 10^6 and made a list of primes and accessed the nth prime number by the index.

Comment: This solution is very fast, see benchmark in my answer. However, finding an appropriate size is tricky. With 10^6 you can calculate the 78498-*th* prime number, but it seems like there is no way to know this beforehand. What if you wanted to compute the 10^5-*th* prime number – how big should the sieve be?

Comment: Apparently there is a way to find a good sieve size, see [wikipedia: *prime-counting function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) and the function `findSieveSize` in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/154292/185595).

Comment: @Socowi the 10^5 th prime number is 1299709. So the seive required should be of size 1299709 + 1 = 1299710.

Comment: I could have looked that up myself, but your program couldn't. It would have to calculate the 10^5-th prime number to know the sieve size in advance, but it cannot calculate that prime number since it doesn't know how big the sieve should be – a classical *»chicken or the egg«* dilemma.

Comment: @Socowi Yes. This infact the very shortcomings of this very method